# Jmeter - extract different rows from csv for every thread for every iteration

Tags: csv, testing, jmeter

Is there a way to extract from a CSV file two rows (need to give to a sample two rows parameters) and to give a thread and repetitions different rows? I mean first thread first repetition must take first and second row, second thread first iteration must take third and fourth row and so on. But then first user second iteration must take fifth and sixth row and second user second iteration must take 7th and 8th row and so on.

Comment: Can you split CSV file in 2 ones: first and second row to file1, third and forth ones to file2 and so on, and feed two separate steps in the scenario?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go for [__CSVRead() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__CSVRead)

- `${__CSVRead(test.csv,0)}` - read first "column" from the `test.csv` file
- `${__CSVRead(test.csv,1)}` - read second "column" from the `test.csv` file
- `${__CSVRead(test.csv,next)}` - proceed to the next row

So if you do something like:

```
${__CSVRead(test.csv,0)} ${__CSVRead(test.csv,next)} ${__CSVRead(test.csv,0)} ${__CSVRead(test.csv,next)}
```

you will get the required behaviour.

Demo

[image]

used components:

- [__threadNum() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__threadNum) - get the number of the current thread (virtual user)
- [`${__jm__Thread Group__idx}`](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Loop_Controller) - get the current iteration for the Thread Group
- [View Results Tree listener](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#View_Results_Tree) - visualize the values of functions and variables

More information: [How to Pick Different CSV Files at JMeter Runtime](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-to-pick-different-csv-files-at-jmeter-runtime)

Comment: Thank you, it works  But  what if i have csv headers in first line so i have to skip the first csv row?

Comment: 1. You can read the first line with following condition `${__groovy(ctx.getThreadNum() == 0 &&  vars.getIteration() == 1,)}`.  2. You may remove the first row